# TensorFlowにおける変数の和に関して

Tags: python, tensorflow

TensorFlow初学者です。以下の計算ができずに困っています。

まず、以下のような2つの変数を作ります。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

このとき、表示させると当然以下のようになります。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

このとき、以下のプログラムのように、a[0]にb[0]を足すとエラーが表示されてしまいます。(numpyの時のように計算できない)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

numpy形式に変換といったことはせずに、そのままTensor形式で特定の部分だけ計算し、以下のような形で出力することはできないでしょうか。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

よろしければ回答をお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'Variable' object does not support item assignment`というエラーが出るのは、そのオブジェクトがイミュータブルであるということです。

イミュータブルということは、文字列でテストするとわかるのですがそのオブジェクトを変更することができないのでその要素に代入ができません。

```
>>> s = 'abc'
>>> s[0]
'a'
>>> s[0] = 'e'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Tensor形式で特定の部分だけ計算するためには、代入をせずに新しく変数を作る必要があります。そうするのであれば、numpy形式に変換してから計算した方が普通は便利だと思います。